# How to check if a event has already been handled in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events

Is there a way to check if a event has already been handled by a other target or if the target has a default event?

Consider the following example:

```html
<div class="card">
  <h3 class="title">
    <a href="/some/path">Title</a>
  </h3>

  <button>Button</button>
  <input />
  <a href="/some/other/path">Link</a>
</div>

<script>
 function isNotHandledOtherwise(tragetElement) {
   // not sure how to implement this
 }

 function clickHandler(event) {
   if(isNotHandledOtherwise(event.target)){
     event.currentTarget.querySelector('.title a').click();
   }
 }

 document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(el => {
   el.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
 })

</script>
```

A click on the `.card` element should forward the click to the `.title a` element.
But **only if** you click `.card` it self or on a child of `.card` that does not handle the click in any other way.

I looked on the MDN docs for `Event` `UIEvent` and `MouseEvent` but I did not find any information regarding this issue.

Is there any generic solution to this problem?

The only other solution to this problem that I can think of (at the moment) is to check if the `event.target` is of type `a`, `button`, `input` or others that are usually used to for click interactions. But this solution is quite error because almost any HTML element can be made clickable.

Comment: Set a global variable in the handler, and check it.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `event.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: I think more of what he needs to do is just traverse down in the hierarchy when a card is clicked. If he finds an <a> tag, select that element, and use the .click() function on it.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with this?

```
<div class="card">
  <h3 class="title">
    <a href="/some/path">Title</a>
  </h3>

  <button>Button</button>
  <input />
  <a href="/some/other/path">Link</a>
</div>
```

Some new JS.

```
 document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(el => {
   el.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
 })

 function clickHandler(e) {
   const a = e.target.querySelector('h3.title > a')

   if(a) {
     a.click()
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can set a data property on dom element once an event is handled on it.

```js
 function isNotHandledOtherwise(targetEl) {
   // not sure how to implement this
   return targetEl.dataset.clicked === 'true';
 }

 function clickHandler(event) {
   if(isNotHandledOtherwise(event.target)){
     event.currentTarget.querySelector('.title a').click();
     event.target.dataset.clicked = 'true';
   }
 }
```

Comment: Yup, data attributes would be a good way to go. I posted an answer, but I think your's is what he's looking for. AKA, persistant tracking of whether something has already been clicked.